# angular jsplumb community - cannot establish connection - source does not exist

Tags: angularjs, uiview, jsplumb

I have problem with using jsPlumb community edition inside angular ui-view.

I can create draggable elements, but im not able to connect them with jsPlumb.connect - fails with "cannot establish connection - source does not exist".

I tried to select elements by their IDs, by angular.element and neither way was not working.

Does anybody have expirience with this - how to make element connected with jsPlumb inside angular ui-view?

Thanks for replies :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsPlumb/issues/427), your issue has something to do with the scope.